# Iteration over a state object in React doesn't display anything

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, javascript-objects

I'm trying to dynamically display checkboxes that will have the starting value as defined in state. I'm using Material-UI to display ui components.
State is populated on component mount and it looks something like this:

```
tagState: {
  All: true,
  Pizza: false,
  Breakfast: false,
  Chicken: false
}
```

I used Object entries and forEach to create a checkbox for each key in the state like this:

```
<FormControl component="fieldset" className={classes.formControl}>
   <FormGroup>
      {Object.entries(tagState).forEach((tag) =>
         <FormControlLabel 
         control={<Checkbox checked={tag.value} onChange={handleChange} name={tag.key}/>}
         label={tag.key}
         />
       )}
    </FormGroup>
</FormControl>
```

I don't get any errors but I also don't get any output. I have checked with console.log(tag) in the forEach loop and it shows all key value pairs as it should.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use map, forEach does iteration but return nothing.

```
<FormControl component="fieldset" className={classes.formControl}>
   <FormGroup>
      {Object.entries(tagState).map(([key,value]) =>
         <FormControlLabel 
         control={<Checkbox checked={value} onChange={handleChange} name={key}/>}
         label={key}
         />
       )}
    </FormGroup>
</FormControl>
```